# Unable to create a normal curve on Histogram in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, statistics, data-science, histogram

I have been learning Python for Data Science for a few months. I am unable to draw a normal distribution (bell-curve) on a histogram. I have even consulted the answer of my assignment but still it is not helping as well.

The rest of the histogram is working perfectly. I have highlighted the two lines which I assume are creating the error.

Please help.

```
plt.figure(figsize= (8,5))
plt.hist(x= estimate_df['aqi'], histtype= 'bar', bins= 25, density= True, label='Histogram of 10,000 sample values of aqi')

xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100) # generate a grid of 100 values from xmin to xmax.
**p = stats.norm.pdf(x, population_mean, standard_error)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2, label = 'normal curve from central limit theorem')
**
plt.axvline(x= population_mean, color = 'red', label = "Population Mean")
plt.axvline(x = sample_mean, color= 'green', label = "Sample Mean of 50 values")
plt.axvline(x = mean_sample_means['aqi'], color = "black", linestyle = '--', label = "Mean Sample Means of 10,000 Values")
plt.xlabel("Aqi Sample Values")
plt.ylabel("Density")
plt.legend()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 8
      6 xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
      7 x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100) # generate a grid of 100 values from xmin to xmax.
----> 8 p = stats.norm.pdf(x, population_mean, standard_error)
      9 plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2, label = 'normal curve from central limit theorem')
     11 plt.axvline(x= population_mean, color = 'red', label = "Population Mean")

File c:\Users\farru\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:2093, in rv_continuous.pdf(self, x, *args, **kwds)
   2091 args = tuple(map(asarray, args))
   2092 dtyp = np.promote_types(x.dtype, np.float64)
-> 2093 x = np.asarray((x - loc)/scale, dtype=dtyp)
   2094 cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
   2095 cond1 = self._support_mask(x, *args) & (scale > 0)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (2,)
```

I tried with a lot of sources but it isnt't helping me

Comment: I think you should check the `population_mean` and `standard_error`. They should be constants instead of vectors with 2 elements.